# Web based designer for windows workflow foundation

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Apart from WPF based rehosted designer, are there any HTML/HTML5 based workflow designers for **Windows Workflow Foundation** ?

Regards
Prasad

Answer (score 4):

One way is to take your WPF application and package it up as an XBAP. This allows it to run in Internet Explorer. This link provides information on creating XBAP packages and the considerations to take when building them: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: +1, this is the only way to have it in the browser. The rehosted designer is a WPF control so it must be run in XBAP or in a desktop app. There are no web based designer (I've already searched this a lot last year, without success, it's why I choose the xbap way).